# node.js cannot find module xml2js

Tags: linux, node.js, include

I made an application on my machine, and it works well. I uploaded it to the server, and it is crashing with the following error:

```
node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Cannot find module 'xml2js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:289:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:241:25)
    at require (module.js:317:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/node/price/index.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:379:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:305:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:271:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:392:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:108:26)
```

This is how my app starts:

```
var express=require('express');
var http=require('http');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var sys = require('sys');
var util = require('util');
```

I have installed both express and xml2js using npm. I have the exact same version (v0.4.0) for node on my machine and my server.

I have made sure that the path wher xml2js and express reside (/usr/local/lib/node/) is included in the paths where node looks for modules. (I edited the file 'module.js' to print the paths where it is  looking for modules.)

```
node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Cannot find module 'xml2js', in paths: /root/.node_modules,/root/.node_libraries,/usr/local/lib/node,/var/www/node/price/node_modules,/var/www/node/node_modules,/var/www/node_modules,/var/node_modules,/node_modules
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:289:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:241:25)
    at require (module.js:317:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/node/price/index.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:379:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:305:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:271:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:392:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:108:26)
```

So what is wrong? I have the right path, the module is there. Why can't node find it? And the exact same code runs smoothly on my local machine. If it matters, my machine is a Mac, and the server runs CentOS.

Comment: Possibly related: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/61d6cf86f1593e10

Answer (score 17):

```
require.paths.push('/usr/local/lib/node_modules');
```

is no longer valid for node v0.8.1 and above. Instead of using **require.paths.push**, you can set the environment variable **NODE_PATH**

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

or if you install npm modules in your home directory, then

```
export NODE_PATH=~/.npm
```

Answer (score 11):

As spmason mentioned, Node changed how modules are resolved. I've had the same issue as you and resolved it by installing all modules globally (`--global`) and adding `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` to the require before requiring any module:

```
require.paths.push('/usr/local/lib/node_modules');
require('blah'); // it works!
```

Comment: In windows environment, npm installed modules to c:/documents and settings folder of the logged in user .. and for me, I had to create a new 'node_modules' folder in the root of my app.js and copy the xml2js or other modules folders into the new node_modules folder

Comment: My resolution to this issue was to add the npm installation global path (in Windows) to the NODE_PATH environment variable for npm 1.1.36 and nodejs 0.8.2

Comment: if you are upgrading to 0.4.* grunt from 0.3.* grunt, run this: npm install xml2js --save-dev

Answer (score 6):

Node 0.4 changed how [modules](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/modules.html) [are resolved](http://nodejs.org/v0.4_announcement.html) and it [appears that this breaks xml2js](https://github.com/maqr/node-xml2js/issues#issue/6).

Answer (score 3):

Node 0.4 looks in `./node_modules` for modules.
For me it did help to just link the modules directory to my project directory with `ln -s /usr/local/lib/node node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I found that the XML2JS module needs to be installed via npm locally. While I've only tried this on Windows, I've written a blog post [here](http://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/node-cannot-find-module-xml2js)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it in the project instead of the global package directory.

If you're using a `package.json` to manage dependancies then you can just run `npm bundle` in the project directory and then add `require.paths.unshift('./node_modules')` at the top of your app file. In my opinion this is the best practice for all projects (especially considering the speed that the development of node takes place).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simple answer is the current packages for xml2js and xml2js-xpat are busted.

I ended up using node-xml instead. I wish xml2js hadn't been my the first npm module I tried to install.

Answer (score 0):

just make `ln -s /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules`, but before move the content of `node_modules` into the original node library `node` - it helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the npm package with the `-g` flag to make it global

```sh
npm install -g package_name
```